# Azure SQL DB DevOps Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Am trying to deploy Az SQL dacpac through DevOps pipeline:

Code:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ADFConfig/Deploy/ADFConfig.dacpac'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0  
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'


- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ServiceConnection-arm-iv-ea-${{ variables.subCode }}-dw-${{ variables.environmentToDeploy }}-rg-01'
    ServerName: 'iv-ea-${{ variables.subCode }}-sql-dw-${{ variables.environmentToDeploy }}.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: ADFConfig
    SqlUsername: dwadmin
    SqlPassword: $(sqladminpassword)
    DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/ADFConfig.dacpac'
```

Download Artifacts are in:

```
Downloading drop/ADFConfig.dacpac to D:\a\1\a\drop\ADFConfig.dacpac
Downloaded drop/ADFConfig.dacpac to D:\a\1\a\drop\ADFConfig.dacpac
```

SqlAzureDacpacDeployment error is:

```
##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\1\drop\ADFConfig.dacpacCheck
```

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you’re publishing from $(Build.Repository.LocalPath), then downloading to $(System.ArtifactsDirectory), but then asking the deployment task to look in the $(Pipeline.Workspace) directory.

Change $(Pipeline.Workspace) to $(System.ArtifactsDirectory).

Comment: Oops!..thanks Moho.